# Post image using UrlRequest in Kivy

Tags: python, image, post, kivy, urlrequest

How to make post image request using *urlrequest* in *Kivy* (Python).
How to open a image and send and

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I tried to  use the `URLRequest` witch is supported by `kivy`, but couldn't make post with image so i used `threading` to make a post, using `request` in the background while the camera is open and don't freeze when we make the upload.
Part of code: https://github.com/c-mike/kivy-Image-Request